# Swift InputStream status does not match any possible enum values

Tags: ios, swift

I have an InputStream in my iOS app (Swift 4) and check the status a few seconds after opening it. The returned value is 7

```
print(String(self.inputStream!.streamStatus.rawValue)) // prints 7
```

But there is no corresponding entry with the value 7 in the enum described in the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/stream.status

How can the value be 7? How can I get a textual representation of the status?

My guess was that the 7 is maybe a combination of other values that can be obtained by interpreting the 7 binary and looking which bits are 1. So in this case the first 3 bits are 1 (decimal 1,2,4) and they belong to (opening=1, open=2, writing=4). But this seems strange to me

EDIT: As Martin said in the comments, 7 is error.

Comment: `7` is `Stream.Status.error` ...

Comment: The rawValue of that Stream.Status enum is of the type Int, not String, as you can see if you click each case: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/stream.status/1413583-error

Comment: @MartinR You're right. I somehow missed it in the docs. Sorry for that stupid question

Comment: Is there a way to get a more detailed error description? What I want to do is to check if the connection fails because the IP / port is not reachable or if there is an timeout, etc.

Comment: @SimonH: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/stream/1416359-streamerror